# applicationContext sample file

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

Am searching about standard form for the file applicationContext.xml in Spring framework. Every time I try to run the application in GlassFish , it says bad applicationContext file. Could you please provide me with sample one ?

Comment: in what way does it say the file is bad, probably a good idea to understand the issues being faced, rather than just copying and pasting

Comment: Please provide some details, e.g. the stacktrace and the context.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can donwload any samples from https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/